# Matrix column addition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Suppose you have a matrix in the form of:
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
a\\
b\end{array}\right]$$

How can this be represented be a two by two matrix?

Comment: This is just for some personal work on parametrizing equations and transformations

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are vector-rows in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: It is to input it into Wolfram alpha, apparently they can do (2x2)x(2x2) multiplication FINE. But not (2x1)x(2x2)

Comment: If you are interested in the action of a $2 \times 2$ matrix on $\left[\begin{array}{c}
a\\
b\end{array}\right]$ then you can let $A$ be the $2 \times 2$ matrix with column vectors $v=\left[\begin{array}{c}
a\\
b\end{array}\right]$. Then for any $2 \times 2$ matrix $B$, $BA=(Bv, Bv)$.

Comment: No one can do $(2 \times 1) \times (2 \times 2)$ multiplication because you have the order reversed. Try $( 2 \times 2) \times (2 \times 1)$.

Comment: Not looking to multiply them, just to represent a 2x1 by a 2x2 matrix

Answer (score 0):

For exmaple you can do the following: Note that 
$$
W:=\{\begin{pmatrix}a & 0\\
b & 0
\end{pmatrix}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}
$$

is closed under addition and multiplication by scalar, since the zero
vector is also in $W$, it follows that $W$ is a sub vector space
of $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Clearly 
$$
\dim(W)=2
$$

and there is a natural way of defining an isomorphism 
$$
T:\,\mathbb{R}^{2}\to W
$$

and you can represent $v$ as $T(v)$ which is a $2\times2$ matrix.

This can be done with any sub vector space of dimension $2$ of $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$
in a similar manner